# debugging my binary tree searching sum algo

Tags: python, binary-tree

Question is very simple we have check whether there is root to leaf path with its sum equal to S(sum given to find).

task:
Complete the function hasPathSum() which takes root node and target sum S as input parameter and returns true if path exists otherwise it returns false.

my code is correct according to my debugging but getting an error for few test cases.
my code below

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.data = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
def hasPathSum(root, S):
    '''
    :param root: root of given tree.
    :param sm: root to leaf sum
    :return: true or false
    '''
    if root==None:
        return 0
    if S==0:
        return 1
    if S==root.data:
        return 1
    if S>root.data:
        b=S-root.data
    else:
        return 0
    return hasPathSum(root.left,b) or hasPathSum(root.right,b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are supposed to check if the current node is a leaf node before returning true

Consider a simple tree:

```
   2
 /  \
1    3
```

Calling `hasPathSum(root, 2)` would return 1 since `S==root.data` is true although it is not a path to the leaf node.

You can fix it like:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.data = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def hasPathSum(root, S):
    '''
    :param root: root of given tree.
    :param sm: root to leaf sum
    :return: true or false
    '''
    if root==None:
        return 0
    # we dont need the S == 0 condition 
    # since the sum can reach 0 before reaching the leaf node
    # check if root is leaf
    if S==root.data and root.left == None and root.right == None: 
        return 1
    if S>root.data:
        b=S-root.data
    else:
        return 0
    return hasPathSum(root.left,b) or hasPathSum(root.right,b)
```

Comment: thanks i did a blunder mistake i was just checking if sum exist or not